# Connect Ruby on Rails to read data from Non Rails Database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm developing Ruby on rails applications and my source data is mysql table that developed by other developer using PHP+Mysql 2 years ago, 
my rails application just need to read and query 5 tables inside old database system (no non modify), is this possibly?

if yes, how can rails can read the model if the table not using standard name convention

( I did some research previously and read about connection_ninja / octopus - easy database sharding, but I would like to give specific question incase one of you have some inputs / experience and want to share it), many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a model to match each table, you can use the following in the model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "PRODUCT" # table name for the model to use
  self.primary_key = "product_id" # primary key of the table
end
```

[Click here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#overriding-the-naming-conventions) for more information about overriding naming conventions for legacy databases.